# Объясните мне как работает строчка рандома из кода count($arr) - 1)]

Tags: php, массивы, случайные-числа, for, foreach

```
     // Дан массив $cars. Состоящий из трех машин со следующими данными: Мерседес - 10000 руб, BMW - 9999 руб, Автобус - 20000 руб.
    $cars = [
        [
            'name' => 'Мерседес',
            'price' => 10000,
            'colors' => [],
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'BMW',
            'price' => 9999,
            'colors' => [],
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Автобус',
            'price' => 20000,
            'colors' => [],
 // 3. Для каждой машины заполните поле colors. В этом поле должны хранится все возможные варианты цветов для этой машины, при чем для каждого этого цвета, есть своя надбавка к стоимости (разная для разных машин)
// Создайте массив colors с цветами доступными для каждой машины. И случайным образом выберите из этого массива по 3 цвета для каждой машины. Эти цвета добавьте в массив $cars в поле colors. Для каждого цвета также укажите случайную надбавку к цене - случайное число от 0 до 100
// Выведите итоговый массив $cars c помощью функции var_dump и убедитесь в его правильности.
$colors = ['красный ', 'синий ', 'черный ', 'серый ', 'сафкари ', 'градинуойд ',];     
 foreach ($cars as $key => $car) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
            $cars[$key]['colors'][] = [
                'name' => $colors[rand(0, count($colors) - 1)],
                'extra' => rand(0, 100),
            ];
        }
    }
    var_dump($cars);
```

Решение верное. Из этого я не понимаю в решении фрагмент 'name' => $colors[rand(0, count($colors) - 1)], а именно count($colors) - 1). По идеи count($colors) подсчитывает количество элементов, а -1 отнимает один из элементов. Каким образом этот код рандомит 1 случайный цвет и как он вносит именно 1 цвет, а не три в 'name' мне не понятно. Объясните пожалуйста логику рандома в этом коде и как потом вносится именно 1 цвет в значение.

Comment: А почему он должен вносить больше чем один? У Вас же в каждой итерации цикла есть `$colors[rand(0, count($colors) - 1)]`, одна итерация = один цвет. При помощи `rand()` выбирается рандомный ключ из массива colors, используется `count($colors) - 1` так как count подсчитывает количество элементов массива где подсчет начинается с единицы, а в массиве первым ключем будет 0, потому для второго параметра `rand()` используется `count($colors) - 1` чтобы вдруг чего максимальное значение Вашего `rand()` не оказалось больше чем длинна массива который у Вас есть.

Comment: Меня сбила сама задача, сказано по 3 цвета, я считала нужно вывести сначала 3 цвета, и уже эти рандомные цвета вносить. А в решении выбирается не по 3 цвета, а по 1 случайному цвету в каждый элемент. Сама я решила это так https://disk.yandex.ru/i/I9v66fZRIYSq9w где в конце не смогла динамически внести данные

Answer (score 1):

`$colors` - это массив, значит элементы в нем проиндексированы числами от 0 и дальше. Если вывести дамп этого массива, то увидим:

```
[
    0 => 'красный ',
    1 => 'синий ', 
    2 => 'черный ', 
    3 => 'серый ', 
    4 => 'сафкари ', 
    5 => 'градинуойд ',
]
```

`rand(x, y)` выдает нам случайное число в диапазоне от **х** до **y**, значит нам надо выбрать число от **0** до **5**

`count($colors)` выдает нам кол-во элементов, т.е. **6**, значит, чтобы получить индекс последнего элемента, нам надо вычесть единицу из общего количества элементов

итого, чтобы получить случайный цвет по индексу из массива $colors получаем формулу:

```
$colors[ rand(0, count($colors) - 1) ]
```

Comment: Поняла, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Один элемент получается из записи:

```
$colors[NUMBER],
```

а `rand` всего лишь генерирует число в диапазоне от 0 до количества элементов в массиве - 1. В итоге получаем например число 5. В итоге из массива происходит взятие элемента по индексу 5. В другой раз `rand` сгенерирует например 8  и тогда из массива `$colors` возьмётся один элемент по индексу 8

Comment: Спасибо. Стало понятнее. В данном случае получается от 0 до 6. Прошел первый раз получил индекс 3, второй раз 1. Это в моем понимании код должен выглядеть так: 'name' => $colors[rand(0, count($colors))], Но что делает -1?

Comment: @ЕленаКрючкина т.к. массив начинается с нуля, а `count` возвращает количество элементов в массиве, то надо вычесть единицу, чтобы не выпасть за границы масивы. Например массив из 3 элементов. Соответственно индексы будут 0,1,2. А count вернёт 3 (столько элементов), а надо, чтобы последняя цифра была 2, поэтому вычитается 1

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение!